# String replace not working in function

Tags: c#, asp.net

string input= "hello, how are you tod&#97y"
i knw the encode is not in proper format thats why i am using a function to replace improper "tod&#97y" to "today".

f1(input);
but at time of comparing

```
if  (input.Contains("today") == true)
{
    lbldisplay.Text = str1;
}
```

it returing false,i have debugged the program.it is working correctly till replace s1.Replace("&#97","a");(shown "hello, how are you today") but at return statement return s1; it is returning original value i.e "hello, how are you tod&#97y".

```
public string f1(string s1)
{
    s1 = s1.Replace("&#97", "a");
    return s1;       
}
```

please help.thank you.

Comment: Your code is correct. I am not sure what is not working there unless you didn't return f1 function on a string.

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely what is happening is that you're not assigning the return value back to your variable when you call it.  The parameter is not declared `ref` so this will have no effect:

```
f1(input);
```

You would need to use this:

```
input = f1(input);
```

Comment: thank you.my silly mistake :p.thank you once again.